# what difference between directly return'this' and indirectly return 'object'? when creating jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

i created one jQuery plugin

```
(function($) {
    'use strict';

    $.fn.charCount = function() {

return this.each(function(index,element){
  $(element).keyup(function updateCharCounter() {
        var $me = $(this),
            maxLength = parseInt($me.attr('maxlength'), 10),
            charCount = $me.val().length,
            $counter = $me.siblings('.limit');

        $counter.text('limit: ' + maxLength + ' characters. remainig: ' + (maxLength - charCount));

    });
});

    }
}(jQuery));
```

above code it's ok and work because i directly `return this` object

but when i change code to indirect object plugin does not work

```
(function($) {
    'use strict';

    $.fn.charCount = function() {
$oThis=this;
$oThis.each(function(index,element){
  $(element).keyup(function updateCharCounter() {
        var $me = $(this),
            maxLength = parseInt($me.attr('maxlength'), 10),
            charCount = $me.val().length,
            $counter = $me.siblings('.limit');

        $counter.text('limit: ' + maxLength + ' characters. remainig: ' + (maxLength - charCount));

    });
 });
 return $oThis;
    }
}(jQuery));
```

you can watch this plugin :https://jsfiddle.net/djary/yo6nLmzg/3/
what difference between `directly` and `indirect` `return this`

why in this case return `this.each` is work but `$oThis` not work?
Where is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the console you can see the error is `$oThis is not defined`. This is because you specified `use strict`. That means that *all* variable definitions must be prefixed with `var` - as is good practice. You cannot be lazy and let the JS engine define the variable to the highest scope for you.

To fix the issue just use `var $oThis = this;`

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/yo6nLmzg/6/)

Also note that I fixed the typo: `remainig` should be `remaining`.